# Not sure what this tool is called

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure if this is off topic or not, if it is i will gladly delete.
I am converting one of my companies utility programs to C#.NET in winforms it is written in vb6, DEFINITELY NOT .NET as it is 15 years old. and in the UI it has a tool which looks like this

[image]

it acts like a folder browser put stays on the UI unlike a folder browser dialog which is a popup. is there a .NET tool which does the same thing or do i have to use a folder browser dialog. ideally i would like to keep it on the screen because i think it looks better to keep it on the screen rather than a separate box. if anyone knows if this is actually a tool in C#.NET winforms or not that would be great

Comment: Could you specify the UI framework you're targeting in C#? Answers to this will vary greatly between Forms, WPF, or others

Comment: are you converting it to a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: @Aravol always miss that out with C# questions :D its winforms, edited the question now

Comment: @DavidL Yes I agree. Just wanted to leave a link which might be useful.

Comment: @DavidL I don't think this is of-topic as it specifically asks if such a component exist in the .NET framework.

Comment: I agree with @Magnus. It seems more a duplicate

Comment: @Magnus I see your point, although the wording is tricky in the close reasons: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  That said, happy to vote to close it as a dupe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes these controls are no longer avaiable in .net, you can create one yourself relatively easily, here is a MSDN link describing what you want

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645(v=vs.110).aspx